# C# Regex with not necessary text

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse some html text that can appear as either of 2 different types of links

```
1. <a href="http://freelistenonline.com/">Site</a>
2. <a class="mobile" href="http://m.freelistenonline.com/">Site</a>
```

I made the following RegEx :

```
<a[\s]*class="(?<class>[\w\W]*?)"[\s]*href="(?<link>[\w\W]*?)">
```

which works for the 2nd case, but not for the 1st case. How should I change it to work for both? I need to identify portions, such as param **class="mobile"**, are not necessary in the text. So how do I modify the RegEx to make the portion of the string containing **class="(?[\w\W]*?)"[\s]*** optional? What is the syntax for it?

Duke

Comment: `a[\s]*class` would also match `aclass` with no space, which i doubt is what you want.  Use `+` (one or more) instead of `*` (zero or more).

Comment: Have you considered using an html parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem - put a zero-or-more repeat on the 'class' portion. As it is now, the test string *must* contain this section, hence the first string fails:

```
<a[\s]+(class="(?<class>[\w\W]*?)")*[\s]*href="(?<link>[\w\W]*?)">
```

Edit to incorporate fix for aclass match noted in comments by rory.ap

Comment: Thanks! ( )* - it is what I need here